# Will there be any way to effectively log exceptions with GWT Superdevmode (Firefox & Chrome)

Tags: java, gwt

Logs like:

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : this$static is null 0.js:31895
undefined 0.js:31901:2
$log_5() 0.js:31901
$logException() 0.js:31909
onUncaughtException_0() 0.js:31929
entry0() 0.js:8401
entry_0/<()
```

That is show in the Firefox console **is not really helpful at all**. What could be done to make logging with GWT SuperDevMode not really this painful? Is there an antidote for this missing GWT feature for Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/He7Q5NBIQZU).

The recent versions of Chrome support SourceMaps for stack traces but apparently there are some [issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=9046) in `GWT`. 
There seems to be a workaround (see #4 in the issue linked above or here for the [gist](https://gist.github.com/jnehlmeier/cddbc476fd330b1d4999)).

Comment: Thanks I will look into this, I think I am already using that class, but thats not working 100% time, I mean not really triggering even there's an exception thrown.